# How to create dictionaries in one column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want an empty column in pandas. For example, data['dict']. I want every element in this column to be an empty dictionary. For example:

```
>>> data['dict']

{}
{}
{}
{}
```

How to write code? Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension.

For existing DataFrame:

```
df['dict'] = [{} for _ in range(len(df))]
```

For new object:

```
pd.DataFrame([{} for _ in range(100)])
```

One caution is that you lose some of the abilities of Pandas to vectorize operations when you use a complex Pandas data structure inside each (row, column) cell.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid the same copy and create the feature problem when assign the values.

```
df['dict']=df.apply(lambda x : {},axis=1)
df
Out[730]: 
     0    1  2 dict
0    a    b  c   {}
1    a  NaN  b   {}
2  NaN    t  a   {}
3    a    d  b   {}
```